# OleDbDataReader not giving same results as SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, clob, oledbdatareader

The following query on my oracle db gives results that look fine when run in SQL Developer.

```
select * 
from guideline$ a left outer join textfragment$ t 
    on (a.TEXTFRAGMENT_CODE = t.TEXTFRAGMENT$_CODE) 
start with a.knowledge$_Code = 71122 and a.guideline$_pcode is null
connect by prior a.guideline$_Code = a.guideline$_pcode 
order SIBLINGS by a.tag_order
```

All rows are populated correctly. When the same exact query is ran in my program using `OleDbReader.ExecuteReader()` some of the rows contain a null value for a specific column when they didn't in my SQL Developer results. The data type of that column is CLOB. I can not see any pattern as to why some of the rows have a null value and some do not.

Not sure what other information would be helpful...

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be going on?

Comment: Which method do you use to read the value of the CLOB column? `GetBytes()`?

Comment: GetValue(), and then Convert.ToString()... (I didn't write this code)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to the way that binary data is retrieved with `OleDbDataReader`.

You should use `GetBytes()`, and follow [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, looks promising

Comment: keep getting an InvalidCastException when I try and use GetBytes() or GetChars()

Comment: Which OleDb driver are you using?

Comment: 11.2.0.1, I think that's what you're asking

Comment: I mean, Microsoft? Oracle?

Comment: Given that version number, I would say that it's the Oracle provider, isn't it?

Comment: Yes Oracle, and yeah GetBytes, GetChars, GetString all give an InvalidCastException. Even before I try and read any data if I break in the debugger and enumerate the results only some of the rows have the data and some are null.

Comment: Have you tried to call `GetString`only for those records with CLOB columns where `IsDBNull`returns `false`?